# Can I download applications/programs that are Mac specific on my Windows PC ?

Tags: applications

Can I download applications/programs, dmg image files etc that are Mac specific on my Windows PC when and where necessary, and then transfer them to my Apple Computer, with no loss of function ?

Comment: Yes and vide versa unless they need to connect to the network during the install which most don't as they install via a copy

Comment: Thats really convenient as I use both platforms, thankyou for your response

Comment: Someone should reopen this. There's nothing remotely unusual or inappropriate about it. Just because you think it's an easy question doesn't mean it can't assist others.

Comment: Most people I know, use both Macs and PCs in there daily lives(they work with PCs and have a Mac at home, this is particularly applicable to students) so I fail to understand why my question is too localized and the blurb that goes with it underneath, when actually it probably applicable to 90% of Mac users. How it is unlikely to help future visitors is beyond me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes. Most application downloads are packaged either as a .dmg (Disk iMaGe) file, or as a package, ending in either .pkg or .mpkg. A .dmg is a regular file on Mac, Win, Linux, etc., so all you have to do is follow your usual transfer method and you can easily move it from PC to Mac.

On the other hand, .(m)pkg "files" are actually directories (just like the .app files in the Applications directory) so you need to take care to copy the entire directory from one device to the next. You can then install it like usual. However, many .(m)pkg packages are actually downloaded as .dmg files, so you shouldn't have any issues at all. Good luck!

Comment: Thankyou for your official answer, thats very kind of you. It is also a alot better & clearer to understand than the first official answer that was posted here, and subsequently taken away !!